# Fetching records of an Object whose particular field got updated in past hour

Tags: apex, soql, batch, workflow

I am running an hourly batch. This batch should pick all the records of an object say abc__c whose particular field Eligible__c is set to true in past one hour. I am trying to fetch these records by having a  field maintained in the object that gets updated with the time stamp when the field is set to true using workflow field update. I am using the following query in my batch apex `start()` method.

```
DateTime curTime = datetime.now();
String queryToProcess = 'select id, name from abc__c where Eligible__c = true and MarkedEligibleTime__c <= :curTime';
```

Here I am comparing the field MarkedEligibleTime__c (that maintains time stamp) against  the current time when batch is running and if it is less than the current time then I am picking the corresponding records. After batch is processed will ensure that MarkedEligibleTime__c is reset so that it doesn't get picked in next hourly batch. Is it the right approach to do or is there a better approach to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can wait until the Winter '14 rollout it looks like there is a new method which does might be helpful.

```
Database.getUpdated(String sobjectType, Datetime startDate, Datetime endDate)
```

> Returns the list of individual records that have been updated for an
>   sObject type within the specified start and end dates and times. The
>   sObjectType argument is the sObject type name for which to get the
>   updated records, such as account or merchandise__c. The startDate
>   argument is the start date and time of the updated records time
>   window. The endDate argument is the end date and time of the updated
>   records time window. Results are returned for no more than 30 days
>   previous to the day the call is executed.

---- edit ----

Having re-read your question, whether this is going to be useful depends on volumes of data I think. It would let you retrieve every record updated in the last hour without you needing to maintain a timestamp field. But you would still need to loop through everything to find the ones where just your field has changed, which could be a problem depending on your data volumes. So probably your approach is better, and I just got carried away with the new Database features!

Comment: That's an awesome feature to have, though. It's been in the API for ages.